# Two columns AutoIncrement MySql

Tags: php, mysql, database

Column1 Id= 100001
Column2 R-Id= RMOB001

For column2 it should add the last three digits of column1, and both should be auto increment.
How can I do this?

Comment: You can't have two autoincrement columns.... what you can do is exactly what you said, take the three digits of column1 and append that to your prefix, but easiest done under program control when you need to display the record

Comment: so what you me to do is fetch id and insert R-id+string(id+1) into table right?

Comment: @Barranka i ain't get you. Can you explain please.

Comment: why this question was down voted? After checking complete site i asked my question, I didn't found answer for question that i'm looking for.there are similar questions but not exactly what i want..

Comment: As for my suggestion, the `mod()` function in MySQL will give you the residual of a division. So `mod(x, 1000)` (with `x` being a non-negative integer) will return the last three digits of the number (you may need to use the `lpad()`  function to fill with zeros the positions.

Comment: As for the downvote, I think it's because your question does not show any effort by you to solve the problem. Stack Overflow is not a place to ask for ready-to-use solutions, it's a place to ask specific questions and get (or give) specific answers. You must do your homework before asking. Please [read this article](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: @Barranka, your link made my day., honestly i appreciate your help for posting that link. It's just awesome. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have two autoincrement column in MySQL. Also auto-increment columns can only be numbers.

What you need is to do it programmatically.

```
insert into table set ...;
select LAST_INSERTED_ID(); // this gets you the newly added auto increment id
update table set column2='your new auto increment ID here' where id= (the id you got in response to the query above)
```

Comment: i'm sorry for stupid question, Do you want me to this in mysql or php?

Comment: use php to execute the stated queries, but replace `your new auto increment ID here`and `(the id you got in response to the query above)`with the corresponding data in the sql queries

Comment: i will accept answer, but column is updating like this..RMOB100001,

Comment: Use `'RMOB'.substr('output of last_inserted_id()', -3)`